# Get access denied error when adding predefined network discovery firewall rule

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, network-discovery

I'm running windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64.

When I access the network tab from start I get a yellow banner saying Network discovery and File sharing are turned off. If I click to change it just reverts to the same message. When I turn Windows firewall off it works fine.

I have tried to turn the stuff on via windows firewall advanced settings, inbound rules, new rule and discovered Predefined was greyed out. After some research I deduced that the issue was the default key and all sub keys was missing from the registry node `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Defaults]`.

I am guessing possibly something to do with removing Symantec end point protection.

I successfully exported the key from another working machine with the same setup and imported to the non-working machine which populated the predefined rules correctly however now get an access denied error while attempting to install the rules.

Does anybody have any idea how or what I have to do to complete the fix?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the solution on answers.microsoft.com

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-discovery-and-file-sharing-wont-stay-on/a12402a4-2826-4a0e-9b5b-45918ce33ef2

Appears to be a corrupted firewall and in the answer thread I found

This Tool does it for you without requiring a working machine to export the file http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/tweaking_com_repair_windows_firewall,2.html

Downloaded the file tweaking.com - repair windows firewall v2.8.8 from the link above and ran it. Total Repair Time: 00:01:26 and now everything is working as it should be.  Odd that I was getting access denied applying the rule but whatever this did it did fix the issue.

It would appear that I had partially fixed the issue by exporting the shred access default rules but still had some other problem.  The tool I ran apparently would have reapplied the default rules also so maybe that it what fixed it.